# Time Series chart showing dates with intervals filled with dots

Tags: looker-studio

I have a datastudio time series chart where the x axis represents the **dates** in a month which is got from a query and the y axis represents the cpu utilization value for a instance, The break down dimension is the instancename.  When I create the time series chart, the x-axis does not display all the datas, it displays dates with **2 days** interval which is filled by **dots**. Is there any way i can fill the dates instead of the dots in a continuous pattern.
[image]

**Update**

As per the given answer below I have updated this question. Now the unnecessary dots have been removed and it displays the dots only for which there is data, but is there any ways that the dates can be continuous for which there is data, ex as per the below chart there is data for all the dates between July8 to July 23 for the particular instance gcp-wsus, but it still displays dates with a 2 day gap interval July8,July11,July14 etc.

Can this gap be filled with dates also? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart, It can be achieved by changing the **Missing Data** value from the default (`Line to Zero`) to `Linear Interpolation`:

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b306e3c3-27bf-4def-92e3-2132fc9f2d6c) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: Changes could be made to the Data Set (e.g. Google Sheets) or there may be individual formulas that could be created in Google Data Studio......however, regarding a more thorough solution, note that forecasting, is a [Planned Feature Release in 2020](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/52681819). Will update the answer when the feature is available.